# Generic Decodable without decoding

Tags: swift, codable

I am using a generic approach to decode JSONresponse generated by AlamoFire. My function is the following :

```
private func fetch<T: Swift.Decodable>(URLRequest: URLRequestConvertible) -> SignalProducer<T, NetworkError> {
    return Network.request(URLRequest)
        .attemptMap { JSON in
            do {
                let jsondata = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: JSON as! [String:Any], options: .prettyPrinted)
                return .success(try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: jsondata))
            } catch let error {
                Logger.shared.error("Error while decoding a JSON", error: error as NSError, userInfo: ["json" : JSON,  "urlRequest" : URLRequest.urlRequest!.debugDescription])
                return .failure(.incorrectDataReturned)
            }
    }
}
```

For each of my request, I have created a struct that follows the Decodable protocol.

For one request, I do not want to decode the JSON because its structure is complex and because I just need to send it back in another request, I just want to save the response in a struct for instance like this one :

```
struct GenericResponse: Swift.Decodable {
    let data: Data
}
```

where data is the response. So, I just want to take the response and put it in a struct without further decoding.

Is it possible without braking the genericity of my function ? Is their a way to build a decoder that do not decode if T.self is of a certain type ?

Comment: if the function worked already for other types, it should work for you Generic Response because Data type is a Codable type.  Did you try and have an issue?

Comment: No. I thought that Data was not Codable. I'll check.

Comment: Why do you receive a dictionary, serialize it to JSON and deserialize (decode) it? That's pretty cumbersome. It's much more efficient to receive raw data directly. And never use `.prettyPrinted` if you are not going to read the output.

Comment: Ideally, split your method into two methods. Create a method that will send the request and return `Data` and then create a second wrapper method that will parse the generic. Then you will be able to call the low level method without even trying to parse.

Comment: @Augie. It doesn't work. It may be a question of CodingKey. My struct field is name is "data". What is the codingKey of a Data object ?

Comment: @user3239711 since you haven't explicitly defined coding keys, the property name 'data' has become your coding key. Is that the highest level key value in your jsonData dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid the decoding of a specific response, you can overload the `fetch` function to handle that case.

See the following example where the second fetch `method` is overloaded to save the response data inside a struct instead of going through the decoding process.

```
typealias JSON = [String: Any]

protocol RawResponse {
  init(data: Data)
}

// 1
func fetch<T: Decodable>(json: JSON) -> T? {
  guard let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: []),
    let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: jsonData) else {
      return nil
  }
  return response
}

// 2
func fetch<T: RawResponse>(json: JSON) -> T? {
  guard let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: []) else {
    return nil
  }
  return T(data: jsonData)
}
```

With this overload, if a response `struct` conforms to `RawResponse` instead of `Decodable` (as we don't need to actually decode the data), the `fetch` overload is triggered.

```
struct UserResponse: Decodable {
  var username: String
}

let userJson: JSON = [
  "username": "someUser"
]
let user: UserResponse? = fetch(json: userJson) // call fetch #1
user?.username // someUser


struct GenericResponse: RawResponse {
  var data: Data
}

let notParsable: JSON = [
  "someKey": "someValue"
]
let rawData: GenericResponse? = fetch(json: notParsable) // call fetch #2
rawData?.data // 23 bytes
```

Comment: Amazing! This solution is really elegant and concise, and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I dont really understand what you are trying to achieve. But I faced this situation where I needed to decode using Generics.

That is why I wrote a DecoderHelper class that enables me to decode Generic Array or Generic Object (depends on your JSON response).

Maybe it can inspire you, and you will find how to optimize it or understand your situation/issue.

```
final class DecoderHelper {

    static func decodeGenericObject<T: Decodable>(data: Data, completion : (Result<T, ErrorResult>) -> Void) {

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
            completion(Result.success(decodedData))
        } catch {
            completion(Result.failure(.decoder(error: error)))
        }
    }

    static func decodeGenericArray<T: Decodable>(data: Data, completion : (Result<[T], ErrorResult>) -> Void) {

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode([T].self, from: data)
            completion(Result.success(decodedData))
        } catch {
            completion(Result.failure(.decoder(error: error)))
        }
    }
}
```

**PS:** Why do you want to send it to an other request because "the JSON structure is too complex" ?

It's pretty simple to parse a JSON file now with the Codable protocol.

Give it a try and train yourself, now that I'm comfortable with it, I love parsing JSON.

Comment: Actually, I don't need the data embedded in that Json. I just need to post it to another server. It's a special case. And I don't want to decode and encode for that.